# Compilation issues with method overloading

Tags: java, compiler-construction, overloading

I was working on a personal project and overloaded some methods in Java so as to make things easier to call and read. And then I started thinking about how the compiler does the correct assignment of the called method. Could anyone explain to me in more detail what issues the compiler might face when we overload methods?

Aside from having to type and signature check each and every single one of the existing methods with that name, is there something else at stake? Or how does it know exactly which method will be called?

Comment: Can you show the concrete code, which you are having trouble with?

Comment: I dont think he has any problems , looks just as a discussion to me

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2 for overload resolution details. If you have specific questions after that, please ask them *with specifics*.

Comment: Search for "dispatch" and "virtual method table"

Comment: according to me : the scope of overloading is limited to the same class (inheritance is overridding) so a lot of complexity is reduced here itself . secondly the only thing modified in overloading is the parameter type (return type is not considered) , so there doesnot looks much of an over head involved . Note that overloading is managed at compile time (while over riding is run time) so the question would be more appropriate for method over ridding